# Firebase Custom Token Does Not Refresh

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I am using Ionic 2 with Firebase Client SDK. My app authentication strategy is:

1. Use sign in with email and password and get ID token from Firebase on my Ionic 2 app.
2. Use the ID token to verify the user and get custom token from my own server.
3. Use the custom token received to sign in with custom token on my Ionic 2 app.
4. Save the the new token to use Firebase Realtime Database and Storage.

I understand that ID token has a maximum age of 3,600 seconds but I am under the impression that ID token is automatically refreshed by the Firebase SDK using the refresh token. Unfortunately, I do not see that this is happening as I need to use get token to refresh the token.

Is there something wrong in any of my steps?

Comment: Is the session getting expired? Do you get any errors? When you call 'getToken' to refresh the token, is it to call your back end?

Comment: @Gerardo Yes, the session getting expired but I do not get any errors. I only know about it since the app keeps getting 401 as or unauthorised to access Firebase. The 'getToken' is to get Token from Firebase for now. Should I refresh token on my own? I thought that by using Firebase SDK, the token is refresh automatically...